# Pythonで多次元辞書の中から特定の要素があるか検索し、あれば値を取得したい

Tags: python

Pythonで、以下のような辞書があった場合

```
fruitsDict = {'fruitsA': {'name': 'apple', 'price': 100}, 'fruitsB': {'name': 'banana', 'price': 110},'fruitsC': {'name': 'orange', 'price': 200}}
```

nameに'orange'が含まれる要素があるかどうかを探して
あればpriceの値を取得するにはどうしたら良いですか？

なければNoneなどの値を取得したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

辞書fruitsDict内の値(辞書)から子辞書のリストを作って、子辞書のキーが'orange'の値(price)のリストを作るコードの例です。

```
# nameに'orange'が含まれるprice
price = [v['price'] for v in [v for v in fruitsDict.values()] if 'orange' in v['name']]
# nameが'orange'のprice
price = [v['price'] for v in [v for v in fruitsDict.values()] if v['name'] == 'orange']
```

該当するものがなければ空のリストになります。